# Query across multiple datasets and a dynamic date range in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a query that collects data from a dynamic date range (last 7 days) from one dataset in BigQuery - my data source is Google Analytics, so I have other datasets connected with identical schema. I'd like my query to also return data from other datasets, usually I would use a UNION ALL for this, but my query contains a complex categorization query which needs to be updated regularly and I'd rather not do this multiple times for each set.

Could you advise on how to query across datasets, or suggest a more elegant way to handle the UNION ALL approach?

```
SELECT
  Date,
  COUNT(DISTINCT VisitId) AS users,
  COUNT(VisitId) AS sessions,
  SUM(totals.transactions) AS orders,
  CASE
  # Organic Search - Google
    WHEN ( channelGrouping LIKE "Organic Search"
    OR trafficSource.source LIKE "com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox")
  AND trafficSource.source LIKE "%google%" THEN "Organic Search - Google"
    ELSE "Other"
  END AS Channel,
  hits.page.hostname AS site
FROM
  `xxx.dataset1.ga_sessions_20*`
CROSS JOIN
  UNNEST (hits) AS hits
WHERE
  parse_DATE('%y%m%d',
    _table_suffix) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 7 day)
  AND DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 day)
AND totals.visits = 1
AND hits.isEntrance IS TRUE
GROUP BY
  Date,
  Channel,
  hits.isEntrance
ORDER BY
  Users DESC
```

UPDATE: I have got as far as follows thanks to the responses below, the following queries all datasets in the UNION but the date range is not applying, instead all data is being queried, any ideas why it's not picking it up?

```
    SELECT
      Date,
      LOWER(hits.page.hostname) AS site,
      IFNULL(COUNT(VisitId),0) AS sessions,
      IFNULL(SUM(totals.transactions),0) AS orders,
      IFNULL(ROUND(SUM(totals.transactions)/COUNT(VisitId),4),0) AS conv_rate,
    # Channel definition starts here
        CASE
  # Organic Search - Google
    WHEN ( channelGrouping LIKE "Organic Search"
    OR trafficSource.source LIKE "com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox")
  AND trafficSource.source LIKE "%google%" THEN "Organic Search - Google"
    ELSE "Other"
  END AS Channel
    FROM (
      SELECT * FROM `xxx.43786551.ga_sessions_20*` UNION ALL
      SELECT * FROM `xxx.43786097.ga_sessions_20*` UNION ALL
      SELECT * FROM `xxx.43786092.ga_sessions_20*` 
      WHERE PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d',_TABLE_SUFFIX) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY)
      AND DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
    )
    CROSS JOIN UNNEST (hits) AS hits
    WHERE totals.visits = 1
    AND hits.isEntrance IS TRUE
    GROUP BY
      Date,
      channel,
      hits.isEntrance,
      site
    HAVING hits.isEntrance IS TRUE
```

Comment: I don't fully understand what you want.

Comment: @Pentium10 I want to run the same query across multiple datasets without having to write my select clause out several times.

Comment: you need to script it

Comment: @Pentium10 Sorry, script where?

Comment: in order to run the same query over and over again on a different dataset, you need to create some sort of service/API or middle-ware in a programming language, where you code the feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  DATE,
  COUNT(DISTINCT VisitId) AS users,
  COUNT(VisitId) AS sessions,
  SUM(totals.transactions) AS orders,
  CASE
  # Organic Search - Google
    WHEN ( channelGrouping LIKE "Organic Search"
    OR trafficSource.source LIKE "com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox")
  AND trafficSource.source LIKE "%google%" THEN "Organic Search - Google"
    ELSE "Other"
  END AS Channel,
  hits.page.hostname AS site
FROM (
  SELECT * FROM `xxx.dataset1.ga_sessions_20*` WHERE PARSE_DATE('%y%m%d',_TABLE_SUFFIX) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
  UNION ALL SELECT * FROM `xxx.dataset2.ga_sessions_20*` WHERE PARSE_DATE('%y%m%d',_TABLE_SUFFIX) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
  UNION ALL SELECT * FROM `xxx.dataset3.ga_sessions_20*` WHERE PARSE_DATE('%y%m%d',_TABLE_SUFFIX) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
)
CROSS JOIN UNNEST (hits) AS hits
WHERE totals.visits = 1
AND hits.isEntrance IS TRUE
GROUP BY
  DATE,
  Channel,
  site
ORDER BY
  Users DESC
```

Comment: Depending on the size of `ga_sessions` the `SELECT * ` can be quite expensive. If this ends up being an issue for OP maybe selecting only desired fields (`select as struct trafficSource, totals, array(select as struct isEntrance, page.hostname from unnest(hits))...`) might cut considerably some expenses :)

Comment: I think in subquery (as it is in answer) you can safely use `SELECT *` as BigQuery smart enough to use only those columns/fields which are actually used in outer SELECT

Comment: You're right! Just checked here, it's safe to use `select *` indeed. Not sure if this is a recent feature but just now I realized that :)

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant this looks like exactly what I want, however when I run as above I am getting all dates ever, from the first dataset in the union only - what am I missing?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant have managed to resolve the unions (I wasn't grouping by `site`) but the date range is still not applying - it's returning all dates, any suggestions?

Comment: try `PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d'` instead of `PARSE_DATE('%y%m%d'`

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant making that change returns the error: `Failed to parse input string "171203"`

Comment: Also tried changing '.ga_sessions_20*` to `.ga_sessions_*` to allow for the 4 digit year, but this returns `Error: Failed to parse input string "intraday_20180111"` - any way to exclude the intraday table from the query?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant the updated inner clause returns `Error: Syntax error: Expected ")" but got keyword UNION at [77:3]` - when I add `)` after each `DAY` I get `Error: Syntax error: Unexpected keyword UNION at [77:3]` which is the first `UNION`

Comment: i am on go and had typos during copy / pasting. will get back to this issue when back to PC. meantime just try to move WHERE clause from inner select to outer. share result when tried

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant thank you - have tried moving there WHERE into the outer query but then the _TABLE_SUFFIX_ is unexpected.

Comment: check now - i just tested it and it DID worked - i mean union and filtering in only expected days